# Prime factorization of an integer

Tags: beginner, haskell, primes, functional-programming

I have just started learning functional programming (Haskell) for fun after using imperative languages my whole life. I am looking for quick and simple tips from pros on how the particular code I just wrote (a simple program solving a simple task - factoring an integer) can be simplified and made more beautiful.

```
-- FactorInt: Factoring n to prime integers

import Data.Maybe

-- Takes the head maybe
headMaybe :: [t] -> Maybe t
headMaybe [] = Nothing
headMaybe (x:_) = Just x

-- Takes the first available divizor
takeDivizor :: Int -> Maybe Int
takeDivizor n = headMaybe $ filter (\i -> n `mod` i == 0) $ takeWhile (\i -> i^2 <= n) [2..]

-- Takes the maximum power of k in n
maxPower :: Int -> Int -> Int
maxPower n k
    | (n `mod` k) /= 0   = 0
    | otherwise          = 1 + maxPower (n `div` k) k

-- Factors an integer to a list of divizors
factorInt :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
factorInt 1 = []
factorInt n = case (takeDivizor n) of
    Nothing -> [(n, 1)]
    Just a  -> (a, k) : factorInt (n `div` a^k) where k = maxPower n a

-- Pretty printing powers
prettyPowers :: (Int, Int) -> String
prettyPowers (a, 1) = show a
prettyPowers (a, b) = (show a) ++ "^" ++ (show b)

-- Pretty printing factors
prettyFactors :: [(Int, Int)] -> String
prettyFactors factors = foldl1 (\ a b -> a ++ "*" ++ b) $ map prettyPowers factors

-- Program
main = do
    nStr <- getLine
    let n = read nStr :: Int
    putStrLn $ prettyFactors $ factorInt n
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code all looks clear and readable to me. This is basically all performance-related.

It's "divisor"

since you're not dealing with negatives, you can use the more efficient `rem` and `quot` instead of the more mathematically correct `mod` and `div`.
`factorInt 1` should be `[(1,1)]`.

In your `prettyFactors` method you're creating a bunch of left-nested `++`'s. This leads to a quadratic complexity printing method. You can use `foldr1` to switch them to right-nested `++`'s and get linear time, or you could look into the `showS` trick. (this won't really matter since by the time your printing takes a noticeable amount of time the factorization will be taking ages.)
Addendum: In most cases `foldl` and `foldl1` are not what you want. You usually use `foldr` or `foldr1` when you want laziness and `foldl'` or `foldl1'` when you want strictness.

Every time you use `factorInt` you start `takeDivizor` at 2, despite the fact that you might have already tried 2,3,4.. on previous iterations. The simplest way to remedy this would be to just add a parameter to each of them telling them where to start looking for factors.

You check a lot of numbers you don't have to in your `takeDivizor` function, you really only need to look at a list of primes, not `[2..]`

You could modify `maxPower` to make it tail-recursive.

If I were to write this, I would probably leave out the `headMaybe` and `takeDivizor` and write `factorInt` something like this.

```
primes = 2 : [ p | p <- [3,5..], all (\x -> rem p x /= 0) (takeWhile (\x -> x^2 <= p) primes ]

factorInt :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
factorInt 1 = [(1,1)]
factorInt n = f n primes where
  f n (p:ps) | n < x     = []
             | otherwise = let mp = maxPower n p in (p, mp) : f (quot n (p^mp)) ps
```

Note that my implementation of `primes` is far from optimal, you can find better implementations on the [haskell wiki page for primes](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers).

Answer (score 1):

`takeDivizor` is not only misspelled, it is unnecessary and inefficient.  It's unnecessary because `maxPower` is more general.  (`maxPower` returning 0 is also preferable as it avoids the unwieldy `Maybe`.)  It's inefficient because it tests factors starting from 2 with each call.

Here is a small-scale rewrite that eliminates `takeDivizor`.

```
factorInt :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
factorInt 1 = []
factorInt n = factorInt' n (2 : [3, 5..])
  where
    factorInt' 1 _ = []
    factorInt' n a = case maxPower n a of
      0 -> factorInt' n as
      k -> (a, k) : factorInt' (n `div` a^k) as
```

---

If you are willing to decompose the problem differently, you can simplify it further by eliminating `maxPower` in favour of some [list processing](//stackoverflow.com/a/13517443/1157100):

```
import Data.List (group, intercalate)

factorInt :: Int -> [Int]
factorInt 1 = []
factorInt n = factorInt' n (2 : [3, 5..])
  where
    factorInt' 1 _ = []
    factorInt' n a = case n `divMod` a of
      (d, 0) -> a : factorInt' d (a:as)
      (_, _) -> factorInt' n as

prettyFactors :: [Int] -> String
prettyFactors factors = intercalate "*" $ map prettyFactor $ group factors
  where
    prettyFactor [f] = show f
    prettyFactor fs  = (show $ head fs) ++ "^" ++ (show $ length fs)
```

Note that this version produces an empty string when factoring 1.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issues I see look like unfamiliarity with `base`.

`headMaybe` already exists in `Data.Maybe` as `listToMaybe`.

`takeDivisor` is poorly named (take from what?) and not very Haskell-y. A well realized Haskell version would be defined as `listToMaybe . divisors` where `divisors` is a function that returns all of the divisors of a number. However this still isn't quite the right definition because every number is divisible by at the very least 1 and itself (and you skip returning 1) so you're really looking for the first prime factor.

```
divisors :: Int -> [Int]
divisors n = filter (\i -> n `mod` i == 0) [1..n]

firstPrimeFactor :: Int -> Maybe Int
firstPrimeFactor = listToMaybe . init . tail . divisors
```

Note that the divisors now start at 1 and end at `n`, so `firstPrimeFactor` includes `init . tail` in its function composition pipeline. The inclusion of `tail` should be obvious, it causes 1 to be excluded from the list of divisors. `init` is there in case `n` is prime, that way `n` itself isn't included in the list and we get back `Nothing`.

Note also that in your original version using `takeWhile` caused many evaluations of `i^2 <= n`. Instead of testing the elements of the list of possible divisors an important optimization is to cap the list range to `floor (sqrt n)`. Of course if we start getting mathematically rigorous in our optimizations there are many better ways to calculate prime factors (including starting with a list of actual primes), so let's not get lost in the weeds.

An alternate way to implement `firstPrimeFactor` that is closer to your original `takeDivisor` would be to use `find` from `Data.List`. I think this version is important for two reasons. One, there really is a function for everything in `base`; learn it, love it, live it. And two, this implementation reads the most like prose to me, readable code is maintainable and beautiful.

```
firstPrimeFactor :: Int -> Maybe Int
firstPrimeFactor n = find (\d -> n `rem` d == 0) [2..floor (sqrt n)]
```

(It would be even better with "`primes`" in place of the range, given a top-level list of prime values by that name.)

Comment: You need `[2..floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n]`, else you get the error `No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’`.